# OPC UA subscription does not fire DataChanged event

Tags: c#, opc-ua

I have following code for OPC UA C# client. I noticed if the server is rebooted time to time then C# client looses the subscription.

```
m_Subscription = new Subscription(session);
m_Subscription.PublishingEnabled = true;
m_Subscription.PublishingInterval = publishingInterval;
m_Subscription.DataChanged += SubscriptionOnDataChanged;
m_Subscription.NewEvents += SubscriptionOnNewEvents;
m_Subscription.StatusChanged += SubscriptionOnStatusChanged;
m_Subscription.Lifetime = 10000; 
m_Subscription.MaxKeepAliveTime = 10000; 
m_Subscription.Create();
```

With the above code, I loose subscription time to time meaning SubscriptionOnDataChanged is not called.  I was reading the document  and that says "The requested Lifetime may be overridden by the Server. Clients must check the CurrentLifetime property after creating or modifying a Subscription to see the value that the Server will actually use."
What does it mean for C# client? Can any body show or explain me? Should I recreate the subscription when StatusChanged event is fired?

Comment: After you call Create, check the lifetime property again to see what the actual value the server is going to use will be. What server are you using? I've never had a server just delete the subscription, usually the lifetime is very long unless you are running against a demo server.

Comment: In general, when subscriptions are at play, you better not rely on any assumption about the subscription lifetime, regardless of who is making that assumption. As the connection might be broken for any other cause. You should intercept and handle the situation when the connection is broken or the subscription is fallen apart. As I see, you have a `StatusChanged` event. Without knowing the actual client library you are using, I assume that you could handle reconnecting from there.

Comment: I am connecting OPC UA server written in C. Library is coming from unified automation. I see StatusChanged event is called,  do you think I can re create the subscription without caring  the lifetime? Should I put life time to something very long?

Comment: You are focusing on the wrong problem.  Rebooting the server will always invalidate the connection and you must re-connect.  If the OPC client software you use does not tell you about that then you have a problem that is hard to fix.  Do double-check your SubscriptionOnStatusChanged event handler, it needs to react appropriately to the StatusCodes.BadConnectionClosed notification.

Comment: @Hans, actually I don't reboot server by ourselves. Since we use mobile network and we often don't have connection. When the connection is reestablished then sometimes I see command is passed to the server (I see by putty) but nothing come back to client.